# CSS: How can I indent one text area but not another?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to indent this entire form:

```
    <%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build], :html => { :id => "blah_form" }) do |f| %>

        <div class="field">
          <p2>Who are you?</p2>
          <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <p2>What deal are you offering?</p2>
          <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

but I dont want to indent this other text area in this form:

```
    <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

right now my CSS file says:

```
#blah_form input, textarea, b4 {margin-left:80px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#blah_form input, textarea, b4 {margin-left:80px}
```

Are three seperate declarations, try this instead to keep your CSS localised to that form

```
#blah_form input,
#blah_form textarea,
#blah_form b4 
    {margin-left:80px}
```

or maybe create an indent class:

```
.indent {
    margin-left:80px;
}
```

That can be used on all elements that need the indent. You could make the class a little more intelligent to apply the indent to specific nested elements e.g.

```
.indent > div {
    margin-left:80px;
}
```

(Won't work in ie6) This is saying to apply the `margin-left` to all direct children of .indent that are div's.

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to the div around the textarea and use that to remove the margin-left

Eg.

```
<div class="field no-indent">
```

And in your CSS:

```
.no-indent textarea { margin-left:0 }
```

Also your CSS

```
#blah_form input, textarea, b4 {margin-left:80px}
```

Is applying to any inputs inside #blah_form and to ALL textarea's and b4's (which I think you mean as class b4, in which case it should be .b4)